# Using ArcGIS Collector Offline?

Tags: arcgis-online, offline

I'm using the newest version of ArcGIS Collector for Windows on a Surface 3 Tablet.

I'm trying to download my webmap to do some offline data collection, and it has worked prior to today.  Today each time the download progress indicator gets about half way done and then fails. I've uninstalled and reinstalled the program, tried to download at different scales even connected the tablet directly to the ethernet via a usb/ethernet cable...but no luck.

Any thoughts about what might be going on?  Like I said, this was working fine yesterday and there has been no change/update since then to windows or arcgis collector since then that I'm aware of downloading or installing.

Comment: Just give it some time and repeat again. Unfortunately AGOL does this, and system health board doesn't tell complete story. Happened to me few times in the past. Also try morning US hours. It also does it when you try to sync data back to the cloud

Comment: Been repeating for a few hours off and on.  But this in encouraging to hear.

Wasn't aware of the system health board before now.  So thanks for that too!

Comment: Any success? My impression that something not right with their server. I am struggling to create replica of my feature service

Comment: Yeah, I gave it a rest and tried again the next morning.  Worked perfectly the first time.

There does seem to be an issue using a large work area and small map scale.

Answer (score 2):

I also experienced failure to create replicas on all hosted services on Tuesday, the day of the online update. This resolved itself at the end of the day, but no one in my organization were able to go offline in Collector that day.

Felix is right. The health dashboard doesn't reflect all downtimes.  Hopefully this isn't deliberate to skirt the License agreement.

Comment: +1  These things badly hurts my business. A few times I've wasted so much time trying to find my mistake when there was none. Unfortunately I don't know how to attract ESRi attention to this issue. Some sort of petition needed